# Seems to have both NumPy 1.8.2 and 1.10.4 installed, also compatibility issues between rllab and OpenAI gym?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, openai-gym

I'm trying to run environments OpenAI gym ("gym") on some reinforcement learning code I found on github: https://github.com/rllab/rllab.

However, whenever I import gym, I get an error message:

> You have 'numpy' version 1.8.2 installed, but 'gym' requires at least 1.10.4

Straightforward right? However, that leads me to problem 1: I started with a later version  of NumPy (in fact, I upgraded to 1.11.1 a few days ago, before downgrading), but had to downgrade to version "0x9" for rllab to work. That's where version 1.8.2 came from. However, rllab claims to be compatible with gym.

But anyways, I still continued because maybe I could have better luck with version 1.10.4. Because I don't have root access, I use:

```
pip install numpy==1.10.4 --user
```

That works. Then I import gym again, but I still get the same error message! According to python (both in shell and in an IDE), the numpy version is still 1.8.2. Thus problem 2.

In sum:
1. How can I make rllab compatible with gym, given the errors I've seen?
2. How do I uninstall version 1.8.2 without sudo privileges to make sure gym can run?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions below

1. rllab has now been deprecated and is actively maintained as [garage](https://github.com/rlworkgroup/garage/). Garage is completely compatible OpenAI gym and has no 'numpy' version conglicts.
2. Regarding unistall without sudo privileges, you can avoid these issues by simply using [Virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)